# Url string being truncated in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display the below url in a html table. I am trying to display it in a html table. After i read it in jquery, it is being truncated? see my sample code below. here is my sample code. any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            var table = $("#myTable");
            var url = returnUrl();
            table.append("<tr><td><a href='http://" + url + "'>" + "click here" + "</a></td></tr>");
        });


        function returnUrl() {
            var link = "myurl:8080/#/billmeterbil/sip-billmeterbil-aaaa6?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now-5y,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!((meta:(apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:deghiklb_Mpijkbb,negate:!f,value:'1970.1_0909_1'),query:(match:(deghiklb_Mpijkbb:(query:'1970.1_0909_1',type:phrase)))),(meta:(disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:cccc_vvvvvvvv,negate:!f,value:aaaaaaaa_v1_9),query:(match:(cccc_vvvvvvvv:(query:aaaaaaaa_v1_9,type:phrase))))),panels:!((col:7,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Drao-Didoryyy,row:9,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'sip-BSF-Socccerr-ABBBB-Seconds-(estimated)',row:11,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Introduction,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:1,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Azxcvbnmn-by-Ccc-and-Status,row:2,size_x:12,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:Lineee-bb-Statest,row:13,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Test-Statest-(%25)',row:9,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'soap-Kingdom-(%25)',row:16,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Projchan-Kingdom-(%25)',row:19,size_x:12,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Overall-Test-Kingdom-%25,row:12,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-CPU,row:15,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Delta-Didoryyy,row:17,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,columns:!(_source),id:All-data-Search,row:23,size_x:12,size_y:8,sort:!(Created_On,desc),type:search),(col:1,id:soap-RootRoo,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:sip-Projchan,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:'sip%20billmeterbil%20Demo6'))";

            return link;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Url</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How long is it? I gave up scrolling right

Comment: At what point is it truncated

Comment: Can you show what's being outputted?

Comment: Basically,  everything after the singlequote  is being truncated. Below is being outputted:
 
http://myurl:8080/#/billmeterbil/sip-billmeterbil-aaaa6?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now-5y,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!((meta:(apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:deghiklb_Mpijkbb,negate:!f,value:

Answer (score 0):

try and see comment of 'Rohit Batta' below

```
table.append('<tr><td><a href="http://' + url + '">' + 'click here' + '</a></td></tr>');
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qaxdosLt/)

Comment: Why should this fix anything?

Comment: @jfriend00 : Replaced singlequote with double and vice versa. URL parameter contains singlequotes. So, this could not be used directly for string representation. Either use escape characters or doublequotes.

Comment: Then, explain that in your answer.  An answer that only provides code and no explanation is not considered a very complete answer.  The best answers explain the problem and solution in words, not just code.

Answer (score 0):

I Made it work this way:

```
        $("document").ready(function () {
            var table = $("#myTable");
            var url = returnUrl();
            table.append('<tr><td><a href='+returnUrl()+'>' + "click here" + "</a></td></tr>");
        });


        function returnUrl() {
            var link = "myurl:8080/#/billmeterbil/sip-billmeterbil-aaaa6?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now-5y,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!((meta:(apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:deghiklb_Mpijkbb,negate:!f,value:'1970.1_0909_1'),query:(match:(deghiklb_Mpijkbb:(query:'1970.1_0909_1',type:phrase)))),(meta:(disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:cccc_vvvvvvvv,negate:!f,value:aaaaaaaa_v1_9),query:(match:(cccc_vvvvvvvv:(query:aaaaaaaa_v1_9,type:phrase))))),panels:!((col:7,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Drao-Didoryyy,row:9,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'sip-BSF-Socccerr-ABBBB-Seconds-(estimated)',row:11,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Introduction,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:1,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Azxcvbnmn-by-Ccc-and-Status,row:2,size_x:12,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:Lineee-bb-Statest,row:13,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Test-Statest-(%25)',row:9,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'soap-Kingdom-(%25)',row:16,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Projchan-Kingdom-(%25)',row:19,size_x:12,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Overall-Test-Kingdom-%25,row:12,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-CPU,row:15,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Delta-Didoryyy,row:17,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,columns:!(_source),id:All-data-Search,row:23,size_x:12,size_y:8,sort:!(Created_On,desc),type:search),(col:1,id:soap-RootRoo,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:sip-Projchan,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:'sip%20billmeterbil%20Demo6'))";

            return encodeURIComponent("http://"+link);
        }
```

So you had a `"`in your URL which was breaking it, So i used `encodeURIComponent` to tackle that. and also changed the usage of `'` and `"` a bit.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/t21byjd5/)

Answer (score -3):

You have to change your script tag and replace `'` with `"` and vice versa. Because, URL contains `'` character, which is treated as String end for URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            var table = $("#myTable");
            var url = returnUrl();
            table.append('<tr><td><a href="http://' + url + '">' + 'click here' + '</a></td></tr>');
        });


        function returnUrl() {
            var link = "myurl:8080/#/billmeterbil/sip-billmeterbil-aaaa6?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now-5y,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!((meta:(apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:deghiklb_Mpijkbb,negate:!f,value:'1970.1_0909_1'),query:(match:(deghiklb_Mpijkbb:(query:'1970.1_0909_1',type:phrase)))),(meta:(disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:cccc_vvvvvvvv,negate:!f,value:aaaaaaaa_v1_9),query:(match:(cccc_vvvvvvvv:(query:aaaaaaaa_v1_9,type:phrase))))),panels:!((col:7,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Drao-Didoryyy,row:9,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'sip-BSF-Socccerr-ABBBB-Seconds-(estimated)',row:11,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Introduction,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:1,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Azxcvbnmn-by-Ccc-and-Status,row:2,size_x:12,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:Lineee-bb-Statest,row:13,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Test-Statest-(%25)',row:9,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'soap-Kingdom-(%25)',row:16,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Projchan-Kingdom-(%25)',row:19,size_x:12,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Overall-Test-Kingdom-%25,row:12,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-CPU,row:15,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Delta-Didoryyy,row:17,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,columns:!(_source),id:All-data-Search,row:23,size_x:12,size_y:8,sort:!(Created_On,desc),type:search),(col:1,id:soap-RootRoo,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:sip-Projchan,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:'sip%20billmeterbil%20Demo6'))";

            return link;
        }
    </script>
```

Additionally, You should change your script tag location to bottom for better performance. Below link could help you understanding this.

[Put Scripts at the Bottom](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom=)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Url</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </form>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function () {
            var table = $("#myTable");
            var url = returnUrl();
            table.append('<tr><td><a href="http://' + url + '">' + 'click here' + '</a></td></tr>');
        });


        function returnUrl() {
            var link = "myurl:8080/#/billmeterbil/sip-billmeterbil-aaaa6?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,section:0,value:0),time:(from:now-5y,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!((meta:(apply:!t,disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:deghiklb_Mpijkbb,negate:!f,value:'1970.1_0909_1'),query:(match:(deghiklb_Mpijkbb:(query:'1970.1_0909_1',type:phrase)))),(meta:(disabled:!f,index:mydb,key:cccc_vvvvvvvv,negate:!f,value:aaaaaaaa_v1_9),query:(match:(cccc_vvvvvvvv:(query:aaaaaaaa_v1_9,type:phrase))))),panels:!((col:7,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Drao-Didoryyy,row:9,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'sip-BSF-Socccerr-ABBBB-Seconds-(estimated)',row:11,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Introduction,row:1,size_x:12,size_y:1,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Azxcvbnmn-by-Ccc-and-Status,row:2,size_x:12,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:Lineee-bb-Statest,row:13,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Test-Statest-(%25)',row:9,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:'soap-Kingdom-(%25)',row:16,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:'Projchan-Kingdom-(%25)',row:19,size_x:12,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:Overall-Test-Kingdom-%25,row:12,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-CPU,row:15,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,id:sip-BSF-Socccerr-Delta-Didoryyy,row:17,size_x:6,size_y:2,type:diagramdiag),(col:1,columns:!(_source),id:All-data-Search,row:23,size_x:12,size_y:8,sort:!(Created_On,desc),type:search),(col:1,id:soap-RootRoo,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag),(col:7,id:sip-Projchan,row:5,size_x:6,size_y:4,type:diagramdiag)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'*')),title:'sip%20billmeterbil%20Demo6'))";

            return link;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is wrong.  That's what the `$(document).ready()` is for so the script won't execute until after the document is loaded.

Comment: Yes, it is till document is loaded. But, best practices are to use `<script>` tag at bottom.

Comment: But, your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: I have updated the answer with both the suggestions, Answer to question and suggestion for improvement :)